# "da" rilate al A-vorto

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Laŭ PMEG oni neniam uzu *da* rilate al A-vorto, eĉ se ĝi esprimas kvanton, mezuron aŭ nombron ([detalaj reguloj pri da](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/da/detalaj_reguloj.html)):

> La botelo estas plena de/je akvo. [...] Neniam diru *plena da...* aŭ
>   *plene da...*.
>
> Tie ni trovis ĉambron plenan de/je rubaĵoj.

En Tekstaro troviĝas la jenaj frazoj (numerado kaj emfazo estas miaj):

> 1) Pro tio, la Prelongaj stratoj estis **plenaj da** multaj vizaĝoj
>   fremdaj al la lando.
>
> 2) Ŝi estis **plena da** tiuj pensadoj [...]
>
> 3) La unuaj estis **plenaj da** admiro kaj da kompato
>
> 4) [...] lia buŝo estis **plena da** gipso.
>
> 5) La tuta dramo estas **plena da** misteraj eventoj

Ĉu la supraj ekzemploj el Tekstaro estas gramatike malĝustaj?

Estas rimarkinde ke ĉe Tekstaro la kvanto de esprimoj kun *plena da* estas malpli ol dek (neniu zamenhofa), sed tiuj kun *plena de* estas pli ol ducent (okdek zamenhofaj). Parenteze, ĉu oni diru *kvanto de esprimoj* aŭ *kvanto da esprimoj*?

**ALDONAĴO**

Jen ekz-oj el Tekstaro kun *plene da* (laŭ PMEG oni neniam diru *plene da*):

> 1) [...] ili ĝis nun en sia propra, patra lingvo skribas treege
>   malbone kaj **plene da** eraroj
>
> 2) Li juĝos inter la popoloj, inter **plene da** kadavroj
>
> 3) Sed la malvirtuloj havas **plene da** malbono
>
> 4) [...] ĉar estis **plenplene da** proponoj dum tiuj jaroj

La 1) estas zamenhofa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jes, la menciitaj ekzemploj,eĉ la Zamenhofa (kiu venas el la fama teksto "Esenco kaj estontenco...", verkita longe antaŭ la fikso de la normo), estas malĝustaj.

Vi povas kontroli, ĉu eblas *da*, demandante pri la koncerna frazparto. *da*-esprimojn oni ĉiam povas eldemandi (ankaŭ) per *Kiom?*, aliajn esprimojn ne:

- Kiom/Kion vi havas? - Kilogramon da sukero (temas pri kvanto kaj/aŭ speco)
- *Kiom/Kion vi volas - Pecon de tiu torto. (ne temas pri la kvanto, sed la speco)
- *Kiom/Kia estas la botelo? - Plena je akvo. (ne temas pri kvanto, sed kvalito)

Comment: Mi ne tute komprenas vian respondon al la kromdemando. Ĉu oni ne povas demandi _Kiom da esprimoj_? Laŭ mi ja, do kial ne diri _kvanto **da** esprimoj_? Mi trovis pli-malpli egale tiom da trafoj per Tekstaro por "\bkvant\OF de\b" (265) kiom por "\bkvant\OF da\b" (262), kaj po du trafojn por kaj _kvanto de_ kaj _kvanto da_ en PMEG.

Eble ja dependas ĉu estas kvanto de io, kiun oni povas pridemandi per _kiom_, kiel vi diris, sed mi ankoraŭ ne komprenas vian ekzemplon ĉi tie.

Comment: Vi pravas, post _kvanto_ la metado de _da_ kaj _de_ dependas de la difiniteco de la mezurata afero, kiel en aliaj okazoj. Mi forigu tiun parton de mia respondo, ĉar ĝi ne estas sufiĉe klara.

Answer (score 1):

Jes, la ekzemploj el Tekstaro estas gramatike malĝustaj. Ja ekzistas gramitikaj eraroj en la Tekstaro. La ĉefa afero estas kontroli kaj kompari la uzon en la tekstaro por eltrovi ĝeneralajn regulojn de bonaj aŭtoroj.

Estas entute 51 trafoj por "plena(jn) da" en la Tekstaro. Atentu ke la plejmulto de ili estas de du aŭ tri aŭtoroj kiuj simple ripetadas la eraron.

Kelkaj el tiuj 51 trafoj ŝajnas al mi pravigeblaj. Ekzemple:

- Li prenis malgrandan boteleton plenan da orkolora likvoro,

Kiom da orkoloro likvoro li prenis? Plenan botelon, sed la botelo estis malgranda.

Sed eĉ ĉi tie mi hezitas. Se la senco estas "Li prenis malgrandan botelon, kaj la botelo estis plena je orkolora likvoro" - tiam ni eble preferu "plena de/je".

Comment: Oni povus iom pravigi la uzon de _da_ en tiu ekzemplo per tio, ke la _da_-frazo rilatas al _botelon_, ne rekte al _plenan_.

Comment: Jes. Ĉu mi ne efektive diris tion? -- kiom? plenan **botelon** da...

Comment: Ho jes, pardonu. ;-)

Comment: Efektive - dankon por substreki tion.